# Excel VBA Filename Search Return Path

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for help with VBA to find file names listed in an excel `Column A` from a folder and return the file path in `Column B`

The code below works, however if I would like excel to skip the row if the filename cannot be found so that the filepath results are returned in the cell directly next to the filename.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, lr As Long, fPath As String
        Set sh = Sheets(1) 'Change to actual
       lstRw = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=sh.Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
        Set rng = sh.Range("A2:A" & lstRw)
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
            .Show
            fPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        End With
        If Right(fPath, 1) <> "\" Then
            fPath = fPath & "\"
        End If
        fwb = Dir(fPath & "*.*")
        x = 2
        Do While fwb <> ""
            For Each c In rng
                If InStr(LCase(fwb), LCase(c.Value)) > 0 Then
                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & x) = fwb
                    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

                    Set f = fs.GetFile(fPath & fwb)
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & x) = f.Path


                    Set fs = Nothing
                    Set f = Nothing
                    x = x + 1


                End If
            Next
            fwb = Dir
        Loop
        Set sh = Nothing
        Set rng = Nothing
        Sheets(2).Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Do the reverse. i.e use DIR inside the range loop to search if the file exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comments above, use the DIR inside the range loop. See this example.

Here it won't output anything to Col B if the respective cell in Col A doesn't return anything.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long, Lrow As Long
    Dim fPath As String, sPath As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Show
        fPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

    If Right(fPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        fPath = fPath & "\"
    End If

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With sh
        Lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To Lrow
            '~~> Check for partial match
            sPath = fPath & "*" & .Range("A" & i).Value & "*.*"

            If Len(Trim(Dir(sPath))) > 0 Then
                .Range("B" & i).Value = Dir(sPath)
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**Note:** If you do not want a partial match then consider revising

```
sPath = fPath & "*" & .Range("A" & i).Value & "*.*"
```

to

```
sPath = fPath & .Range("A" & i).Value & ".*"
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Last Q, how can I get this to cycle through all subfolders?

Comment: thqt should ideally be a new question... also if u seqrch stackoverflow or google, you will find plenty of examples....